# How to get back to removed comments (particular case)?

Tags: support, feature-request

I've asked [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/1458840/how-to-limit-the-maximum-cpu-resources-for-a-specific-process) and now, that I get back to it showing to a colleague of mine, I notice that portion of the comments have been removed.

I'd like to see those. That would support my claim of *other people mentioning* that it would be a clear security issue to turn off that specific feature. I do support that claim but I'd feel more comfortable being able to prove that it's not only my individual, crazy idea.

Since I'm not even near the rep level to get to the remove comments, I wonder what's the correct procedure to get hold of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only moderators can see deleted comments so if you have a reason to need them then contacting a moderator is the way to go.

In this case though there are no deleted comments. None at all. The comments that currently exist are all there was.

Comment: Thanks (first paragraph) and WTF?! (second paragraph). I'm (almost) totally, entirely, perfectly sure that I've seen those comments. Either I'm going mad, imagining stuff, or I've posted a question elsewhere too. At any rate - thanks.

Comment: @KonradViltersten - Are you sure they were comments to your question?  In any event if those comments are helpful they should have been contained within an answer.

Comment: @Ramhound I am not. Sadly. And I start to suspect that we have a difference of opinion between me and Mrs. Reality. Hard to argue with her, hehe. It might have been comments to someone else's question/answer, yes.

Comment: @KonradViltersten in this case in think Mrs Reality is right. Out of curiosity I wondered if you had *any* comments around that time on other questions. Looking into it the most recent comment you had posted was back in 2018 and your last deleted one was long before that so it wasn't a conversation you were directly involved in, at least not around that time on *this* site.

Comment: @Mokubai I'm afraid that, however embarrassing it is, I might have had a consideration  and stumbled upon a separate conversation, aligning with mine. Then, as the comments in that conversation (made long time before I read it and with no interaction with me whatsoever) was so perfectly spot on to the question I was wondering about, my stupid (or genius) brain made the association and converted it to a "memory". I'm both impressed by my brain and a little bit scared... Like if it can see my thoughts... Well, it can, kind of.  :)